# The reason of bias'es usage in networks?

Tags: networking

It may be easy to see why but I still don't understand why we use bias in a neutral network? The weight's values will get changed, therefore ensuring whether the algorithm will learn. So, why use bias in all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of linear equations.

Bias is *another* learned parameter. A single neuron will compute `w*x + b` where `w` is your weight parameter and `b` your bias.

Perhaps this helps you: Let's assume you are dealing with a 2D euclidian space that you'd like to classify with two labels. You can do that by computing a linear function and then classify everything below it with one label, and everything below with another. If you would not use the bias you could only change the slope of your function and your function would always intersect `(0, 0)`. Bias gives you the possibility to define where that linear function intersects the y-axis for `x=0`, i.e. `(0, y)`. E.g. without bias you could not separate data that is only separatable by the y-axis.

[image]